# Graph Search algorithms vs. graph optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-theory

I have been looking at a lot of graph searches -both informed and uninformed. I have also looked at and coded some optimization problems such as hill-climbing. My question is, **how can I relate the two types of algorithms?**

To be a little more clear, here is an example:
Let's say I run a graph algorithm like Depth first Iterative Deepening. I run it for one depth and get a goal node, then I run it again at a different depth and find a goal node and so on. So now, I have a set of possible goal nodes. Could I run an optimization algorithm like hill climbing to find which one is "optimal" according to different limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the notions you encounter in graph search algorithms is `optimality`. You should consider that here optimality is just about the **algorithm** and **not** about the **goal**. Meaning that, if an algorithm is optimal it should return the `minimum cost` solution.

Now, if you want to optimize something it's completely a different problem. In this case the quality of the **solution** is of most importance not the way you achieve it. 

Algorithms like Genetic Algorithms, PSO, ... and many more optimization methods exists to address this issue.

BTW, sometimes we combine a graph search method like A* with an optimization algorithm to gain better results from the optimization algorithm.

---

Note: The term `Graph Optimization` is not related to the topic `Graph Search` that I think is your main topic according to your question.